# How to cleanly remove a Plone custom permission?

Tags: security, permissions, plone

You know, you start creating a distribution called `something.good` and on it you define a `permissions.zcml` with something like:

```
<configure xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope">

  <permission
     id="something.good.reset"
     title="something.good: reset entries"
     />

</configure>
```

But then, once the distribution is installed on the server, you realize that the permission is not good enough and has to be completely refactored to `something.else`.

Uninstalling `something.good` from `plone_quickinstaller` does not remove the permission. Going to any security tab within ZMI you can still see it.

I looked around for documentation, browsing code in `AccessControl` and `Products.GenericSetup` but couldn't find anything.

Any idea on how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so Plone is easy, don't mind what others may tell you.

So, you (actually I) want to remove a permission definition? **Just do it!**

So the list of things to check to properly remove a permission are:

- remove the permission from `permissions.zcml`

  - if there are no permissions left remove any reference to that file (maybe on your `configure.zcml`)
- remove all references to the permission on `profiles/default/rolemap.xml`
- scan all your `configure.zcml` or python files (if using grok-like permissions) to references to that permission

**And that's it!**

Once you restart your instance the permission will no longer show up on ZMI's Security tab.

Seems that permissions are created on-the-fly at startup time? Seems so to me. Prove me wrong though!

Comment: You are correct; do note that *assignments* of permissions are stored in the ZODB (persisted). Add the permission again to Zope and the assignments of those permissions magically will re-appear.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the note. Any code pointer on how to also clean this up?

Comment: You mean remove the persisted assigment info?

Comment: Yes, anything left persisting should be removed if you want to remove a permission...

Comment: It'll take a full traverse of the object tree to clean that up, btw.

Comment: Question: this will work also for permissions defined in "the old way", using CMFCore setDefaultRoles function?